# Complex promql queries

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have prometheus with metrics of many users. I need to apply some promql functions to EACH metric. Can i create one request to prometheus, to get metrics in desired format?
For example, apply avg on CPU metric and irate on IO at the same time

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, each query/query_range API call can only evaluate one PromQL expression.